# Query same table to create ordering for search screen

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `User` and `RecentSearch` and a screen on a website which allows the user to find other users. The server returns a user array without taking into account the friends and recent searches, I want to include it client side (the client means an iOS app running these queries). **I want friends and recents searches to take precedence from the stuff the server returns**.

I am a bit stuck. I am not sure how to do this. I made a query below, but that doesn't work because it requires all users to have the flag `showOnSearchScreen` set to 1, but that doesn't always apply for friends and recent searches.

The flag `showOnSearchScreen` is **only** set to true for users returned by the server. This means that is possible for a `User` to have flag `showOnSearchScreen` set to 1 and also be friends.

These are my tables:

```
create table User (
    userUuid text not null primary key,
    username text not null,
    showOnSearchScreen int not null,
    friends int not null
);

create table RecentSearch (
    userUuid text not null primary key,
    foreign key (userUuid) references User (userUuid) on delete cascade
);
```

This is my query which does not work (assuming the user is searching for users with a 'g' somewhere):

```
select *,
       case
           when exists(select 1
                       from User CustomUser
                       where User.userUuid = CustomUser.userUuid
                         and CustomUser.friends = 1
                         and CustomUser.username like '%g%') then 2
           else 0 end as friendScore,
       case
           when exists(select 1
                       from RecentSearch
                                join User CustomUser on RecentSearch.userUuid = CustomUser.userUuid and
                                                        User.userUuid = RecentSearch.userUuid
                       where CustomUser.username like '%g%') then 1
           else 0 end as recentSearchScore
from User
-- This is wrong...
where showOnSearchScreen = 1
order by friendScore + recentSearchScore;
```

Must this be resolved with outer joins? I am a bit confused.

So keypoints:

- Server sends `User`s to client, client upserts them in the database and sets flag showOnSearchScreen to 1
- The query should return at least all users with that flag set to 1
- I want users who are friends and have a username similar to the input (I guess  %sometext% would work good enough) to take precedence over the users returned from the server
- Same applies for `User`s from `RecentSearch`, if a user joined from `RecentSearch` has a similar username, take precedence over the users returned from the server (but friends should be shown at the top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC - Consider a `UNION` query that potentially resolves your bullet points using score to determine precedence or ordering:

```sql
SELECT userUuid, username, 3 AS score
FROM User
WHERE friends = 1 
  AND username LIKE '%g%'

UNION

SELECT r.userUuid, u.username, 2 AS score
FROM RecentSearch r
 JOIN User u ON r.userUuid = u.userUuid 
WHERE u.username LIKE '%g%'

UNION

SELECT userUuid, username, 1 AS score
FROM User 
WHERE showOnSearchScreen = 1 
  AND username LIKE '%g%'
```